# How can I tell a AWS Lambda Function to redirect based off the environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, password-less

So currently I'm using AWS Lambdas as triggers for my Cognito Passwordless authentication. For the create_auth_challenge trigger I have an AWS Lambda function that sends a link to the user to redirect them somewhere based on the environment. The only problem is that I'm not sure how to dynamically tell the function which environment the auth request is coming from.

````
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-west-2' });
const SES = new AWS.SES();
exports.handler = async (event,context) => {
    console.log("HERE: ", event,context);
    let secretLoginCode;
    if (!event.request.session || !event.request.session.length) {
        // Generate a new secret login code and send it to the user
        secretLoginCode = Date.now().toString().slice(-4);
        try {
            if ('email' in event.request.userAttributes) {
                const emailResult = await SES.sendEmail({
                    Destination: { ToAddresses: [event.request.userAttributes.email] },
                    Message: {
                        Body: {
                            Html: {
                                Charset: 'UTF-8',
                                Data: `<html><body><p>This is your secret login code:</p>
                           <h3>Your magic link: ${INSERT ENVIRONMENT HERE}/api/auth/cognito/verify?email=${event.request.userAttributes.email}&code=${secretLoginCode}</h3></body></html>`
                            },
                            Text: {
                                Charset: 'UTF-8',
                                Data: `Your magic link: ${INSERT ENVIRONMENT HERE}/api/auth/cognito/verify?email=${event.request.userAttributes.email}&code=${secretLoginCode}`
                            }
                        },
                        Subject: {
                            Charset: 'UTF-8',
                            Data: 'Your magic link'
                        }
                    },
                    Source: 'Company <no-reply@company.com>'
                }).promise();
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    } else {
        // re-use code generated in previous challenge
        const previousChallenge = event.request.session.slice(-1)[0];
        secretLoginCode = previousChallenge.challengeMetadata.match(/CODE-(\d*)/)[1];
    }
    // Add the secret login code to the private challenge parameters
    // so it can be verified by the "Verify Auth Challenge Response" trigger
    event.response.privateChallengeParameters = { secretLoginCode };
    // Add the secret login code to the session so it is available
    // in a next invocation of the "Create Auth Challenge" trigger
    event.response.challengeMetadata = `CODE-${secretLoginCode}`;
    return event;
};```

This is a magic link authentication by the way.
````

Comment: If you have unique Lambda functions, one per environment, then you can simply add a Lambda environment variable to your Lambda function at deployment time (e.g. ENV=prod) and read that in the Lambda function. If multiple runtime environments trigger the same Lambda function then you may have to infer the environment from the `event` or `context` provided when your Lambda is invoked.

Comment: Yea I do have multiple environments so the plan is to dynamically change the redirect but if I go with what you suggest, how would I go about passing the environment through the event or context. My current custom auth challenge flow is like this pre-sign up-> define_auth_challenge auth challenge -> create_auth_challenge -> veryify_auth_challenge

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question. I'm saying that each Lambda function would be deployed with a different value of the ENV environment variable (or whatever you want to call it). It wouldn't be present in the event or context. It's statically available in the environment of each Lambda function. Your deployment tooling would set it accordingly when uploading the Lambda function package for each of prod/qa/dev/whatever.

Comment: I think I'm even more confused haha.

Comment: See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html

Comment: I know I can add environment variables to the Lambda Functions but the one thing I don't quite get is what is the point of adding environment vars if I'm going to make different Lambda Functions.

Comment: It’s the same Lambda code in each environment. Your API consumers hit one of N identical Lambda functions, depending on which environment those consumers are associated with. The Lambda function yields an environment-specific redirect URL based on a Lambda environment variable.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding now. Would all this be for one user pool also? Is there some way we can communicate better haha.

Comment: I just don't understand how you tell the Lambda function what the environment is.